# Could a living donor donate their liver multiple times in their lifetime?

Tags: liver, organ-donation, internal-organs, organ-transplant, organ-damage

While meditating about becoming a living organ donor, I was quite surprised to come across the following:

> Within eight weeks, both the donor's and the recipient's livers will
> be almost completely regenerated

(https://www.ucsfhealth.org/education/living-donor-liver-transplant-the-facts)

and

> How Long Does It Take for a Liver to Regenerate After Donation?
>
> In a few months after surgery, your liver will regenerate back to its
> full size, and return to your pre-donation level of health. The other
> person’s new liver will grow to full size as well, leaving both people
> with healthy, functioning livers.

(https://www.upmc.com/services/transplant/liver/living-donor/process/after)

Due to this amazingly rapid regeneration capacity of the liver, could it be possible in the near future, that a living donor could donate their liver multiple times in their lifetime? If not, what are the chief reasons for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liver donation - *an act of great honor* - should only be done once.

Liver regeneration occurs via compensatory hyperplasia.

> Regeneration of the liver can be more correctly defined as *compensatory hyperplasia* where in the remaining liver tissue expands to meet the metabolic needs of the organism. Unlike anatomic true regeneration, the expanding liver does not regain its original gross anatomical structure.

[Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3976740/)

Thus, the structure is very different and not ideal for another surgery recipient.

Comment: Maybe explaining what hyperplasia is may help differentiate between what you mean with "true regeneration".

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you for the powerful words: "an act of great honor"